# Stratified split of subset of data

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, train-test-split

I have an overall dataset of size 10,000. I'm aware that I can use the stratified split to create training and test set and then I can run it twice (the second time on the test set) to get a validation and test set. I can do this for the 10,000 samples. I know I could use [StratifiedShuffleSplit](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit.html#sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit).

For my work, I need to only use 1,000 samples. Is there a nice way of doing this but only with a subset of the data? I would like to preserve the class percentages from the original 10,000 set, but apply it to a set of 1,000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured it out in case someone else is wondering the same.

I can simply enter the train_size and test_size parameters to be integers. Then I run the split again on the test set with 50/50 to get a validation and test set.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using pandas or numpy for storing your data there are `pandas.DataFrame.sample(1000)` or `numpy.random.choice`

Comment: OP asked for *stratified* splits. If you thing the methods you propose do offer such an option, please clarify this explicitly.